# Using an SQL table without an ID column in Haskell/Persistent

Tags: sql, haskell, persistent, haskell-persistent

I want to use an *existing* database with [Persistent](http://yesodweb.com/book/persistent) using this simplified schema:

```
share [mkPersist sqlSettings, mkMigrate "migrateAll"] [persistLowerCase|
Entity sql=entities
  deriving Show

EntityLink sql=entity_links
  sourceId EntityId
  targetId EntityId
  deriving Show
|]
```

The `entities` table has an `id` column, which is just fine. However, the `entity_links` table does not have one and I do not want to add one. Instead, it has the primary key `(source_id, target_id)`. Whenever I want insert an `EntityLink`, I get this runtime error:

```
SqlError {sqlState = "42703", sqlExecStatus = FatalError, sqlErrorMsg = "column \"id\" does not exist", sqlErrorDetail = "", sqlErrorHint = ""}
```

Here's how I insert an `EntityLink` in the code, given valid `sourceId` and `targetId`:

```
      insert $ EntityLink { entityLinkSourceId = sourceId
                          , entityLinkTargetId = targetId
                          }
```

How can I disable the `id` column in Persistent for the type `EntityLink`?

Comment: use `primary sourceId targetId` in the `EntityLink`.

Comment: Some more discussion here: https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/4nneia/how_to_use_persistent_with_tables_without_id/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `Primary` and specify the columns that belong to the primary key. Like:

```
EntityLink sql=entity_links
  sourceId EntityId
  targetId EntityId
  Primary sourceId targetId
  deriving Show
```